# Exec() method of Visual Studio add-in not triggered on using GwebSearchClient in GoogleSearchAPI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, google-api, visual-studio-addins

In my Visual Studio 2010 add-in, the Exec method of the IDTCommandTarget interface stops triggering (on the relevant menu click) when I add the following line of code to the Exec method:

```
GwebSearchClient client = new GwebSearchClient("www.google.com");
```

On removing the above line, the Exec method gets called as expected.
I'm using the [google-api-for-dotnet](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/) and have (obviously) added the GoogleSearchAPI.dll as a reference to the add-in.

If anyone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A library load exception was being raised as the GoogleSearchAPI.dll was not present in the default paths in which Visual Studio looks for at runtime.
Pasting the dll to one of the default search paths fixed the issue.
Thanks to all who spent time on this.